# Array/Object copy by value/copy by reference mystery

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on a project in Google Apps Script/JS and for some reason I'm getting unexpected behavior when I try to copy an array of objects using the Object.create() method. The relevant snippet of the code is below, and when the function finishes...the original array of objects are modified, even with the second parameter passed in correctly.

```
  WebConfigParser.prototype.compareWith = function(array_of_objs, parameter_flag)
  {
  var safe_array_of_objs = [];
  var array_of_objs_to_touch;
  if(parameter_flag)
  {
    if(parameter_flag === "passbyval")
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < array_of_objs.length; i++)
      {
        safe_array_of_objs.push(Object.create(array_of_objs[i]));
      }
      array_of_objs_to_touch = safe_array_of_objs;
    }

  }
  else
  {
    array_of_objs_to_touch = array_of_objs;
  }
  ///more code happens here...but i'm always referring to "array_of_objs_to_touch"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a deep copy of a single dimensional array, you could use *Array.slice()*

```
var a=[1,2,3],
b=a.slice(), //deep copy
c=a;
a[1]=3;
console.log(a,b,c)
```